# Is there a historic drug shortage database?

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, historical, drugs

I was wondering if there was a historic database of drug shortage data?

The current database (link below) appears to only reflect any shortages that have been resolved in 2017 but does not include shortages resolved in past years.

https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/drugshortages/default.cfm

Comment: Consider asking the FDA directly. It's valuable for government agencies to hear from parties interested in using data that they have, and despite popular caricatures of government officials, most folks working for the government are trying to serve their country and fellow citizens.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question of the FDA on August 2 this year.  Here is a response.  If anyone knows of such a repository, I'd be interested in some analysis.

> From: CDER DRUG SHORTAGES 
>   Sent: Wednesday, August 2, 2017 14:05
>   To: (Redacted)
>   Subject: RE: Historical Drug Shortage Data
>
> Good Afternoon,
>
> For past shortage information, the best place to get an archive of past shortages posted on the FDA database is the WayBackMachine which can be found here: http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.fda.gov.  You type in a url and will get a chart of when the snapshot of that page was taken.  Here is the URL you can use for the drug shortage database:
>
> www.fda.gov/drugs/drugsafety/drugshortages/ucm050792.htm